# Using a significant loading derived from PCA

Tags: pca, modeling

I am currently reading a paper about energy efficiency in housing where the authors carried out PCA to explain the characteristics of dwellings with poor energy efficiency.  They ended up with three components.  Component 1 has a positive significant loading for one characteristic and negative for another; Components 2 and 3 have only positive significant loadings.  The authors then get factor scores for each component.

I've got my own data so I am trying to understand how that significant loading is used.  I thought that I could just multiply the number of dwellings with a certain characteristic by the significant loading they came up with (I was thinking of it as being a "weight" to the population) but I've read a bit more about PCA and I'm sure it can't be simple - can it?

Comment: Can you offer details of the paper? Additional context (both from the paper or from you adding more information) may help

Comment: Done.  Hopefully my interpretation of a significant loading = "weight" isn't too far off of the mark.

Comment: Thanks. An explicit reference (so people can identify context) would be useful, if possible.

Comment: Why do you want to multiply the number of dwellings with a certain characteristic by the loading? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @elliotp - my original question is nearly  nearly 4 years old, it looks like I never updated this question to say it was answered.